Meshing a non-planar surface into planar quads given initial constraints
I have an initial semi-circular surface whose ends are at different Z coordinates (so the surface is non-planar)
The thing looks a little like so (I've meshed this, but you can imagine it as a continuous surface).


I'm required to mesh this surface such that all mesh faces are planar. There are no limits on the number of faces I can have. However, there are other constraints:

The Z coordinates of the starting and ending positions are given and cannot be changed.
The mesh must be a coarse mesh such that all meshed faces are quads, and each quad must extend from the inner arc to the outer arc (no subdivisions allowed)

I've added these conditions on the images for clarity


My question then is three-fold:

Is it even possible to mesh this surface given these conditions ?
If it's possible, what is the minimum number of faces required to achieve this ?
How can we calculate the coordinates of nodes that will make up these faces ?

